# Хранить python dict в .env файле

Tags: python

Мне надо хранить dict (словарь с ключами и значениями) в переменные окружения Linux через файл .env, проект на python 3.6 все работает через docker docker-compose, все скрытые переменные проекта высвечиваются нормально, кроме словаря которого я прописал в .env файл LINES={'key': value1, 'key2': value2}, вместо этого я вижу LINES=38. Вопрос почему вместо значения ключа, стоит число 39?

Comment: Добавьте подробностей, пожалуйста.

Comment: Возможно, что-то перезаписывает ваше значение? Попробуйте создать тем же способом переменную, например, LINES_2 с тем же значением, и посмотрите, что в итоге окажется в ней.

Comment: [mcve] в студию

Comment: Ну и вообще LINES это обычно системная переменная, неудивительно что она перезаписывается системой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `.env` файл является `shell` скриптом, который должен содержать команды понятные интерпретатору `Shell`. Если попытаться выполнить команду `LINES={'key': value1, 'key2': value2}` в UNIX shell, то получим ошибку:

> ```
>     sh-4.1$ LINES={'key': value1, 'key2': value2}
>     sh: value1,: command not found
> ```

2. как вам уже написали в комментариях, LINES - встроенная переменная окружения, показывающая максимальное число строк в терминальном окне:

   ```
   sh-4.1$ echo $LINES
   40
   ```
3. хранить словарь можно в виде JSON строки. Пример:

   задаем переменную окружения в виде JSON строки:

   ```
   sh-4.1$ export DATA='{"key": 11, "key2": 12}'
   ```

   содержимое Python скрипта:

   ```
   import os
   import json

   data = json.loads(os.environ["DATA"])
   print(data["key"], data["key2"])
   ```

   проверка:

   ```
   sh-4.1$ python a.py
   11 12
   ```

Comment: thank you very match))

Comment: @OmaDt, you're very welcome )